# Draft commits on mercurial

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have been committing regularly to a mercurial repo which is managed by Bitbucket. Today when I made a commit as I always do, Bitbucket has marked the commit as "draft" (this has never happened before). Any ideas what a draft commit is?

Comment: I've added a bug report here: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/8678/draft-status-on-commits

Answer (score 11):

I see the same thing.  It looks like there was a [change](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4560/provide-a-method-for-setting-the-phase-of) implemented recently to support phases.  I fixed this by going into the settings for my repo and 1) turning on "This is a non-publishing repository", 2) Saving, then 3) turning it back off.  It may work for you.

Answer (score 8):

A draft is part of the phases framework:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/phases

I am not that familiar with this feature, but it would appear as if Bitbucket possibly changed some setting and is now marking public commits as draft.

I too noticed this, but in the last few minutes, it appears as if the system removed the draft label.

Comment: Thanks Josh. My commit is still marked as draft but good to know that I'm not the only one seeing this :-)

Answer (score 6):

I had issue where TortoiseHG was marking some commits I had just pushed on master as draft. After confirming they had indeed made it to server I was able to simply **right click on the commit** and click "**Change Phase to => Public**"

Comment: have you ever figured out why this seemed to happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know why. I'm no longer using TortoiseHG as I've switched jobs since then.